# how to implement real time notification like facebook in nopcommerce

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

In `nopcommerce` , i want to create real time notification that when a customer reserved a order,after paying and click the button,order's details be sent to admin panel as a notification.i know i should use `SignalR` but i really very new in `SignalR`. how to implement SignalR between two layers means `Nop.Web` and `Nop.Admin`?
can anybody help me and suggest me any references?
how to create a modal notification like `facebook` in nopcommerce or `Asp.Net MVC`?

Comment: No need to use SignalR for notification, refer PM(Private Messaging) in nopcommerce. In a same way you can extend messaging for your requirement

Comment: @Div what do you mean?how can i do that without SignalR?please explain more.

Comment: Read my upper comment again :)